# Thunderebird Account Settings Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: thunderbird

I have been using Thunderbird for a while: now using 91.7.  My primary email comes in from Yahoo.  I realized that as an IMAP all of the emails are still out there.  I want to change it to POP3 so the Yahoo email get deleted.  I made the change in ACCOUNT SETTINGS from IMAP to POP3.  It wouldn't let me connect.

Or is there an option/setting with IMAP that will trash the Yahoo emails and not delete those emails in Thunderbird.

HELP!!!!!!!

Thanks,
Rich Ramik

Answer (score 0):

IMAP keeps your email stored on the server. A local copy, sometimes only of the message header, is what you work with, and your actions are immediately mirrored on the server.

To delete mail from a server while keeping it locally, archive the mail in a local folder.

- Create a folder "Archive" under "Local Folders". Optionally also create folders for each year incoming and outgoing.
- Move mails you want to remove from the Yahoo account to a local folder under Archive. You can select multiple mails at once in your Yahoo account, then either drag them to the local folder, or use the right-click menu to move them. The latter option is more "precise". The destination folder is "remembered" in the move menu so you can move multiple batches. It is not recommended to move very large amounts of emails at once - if a move operation encounters an error, only part of the messages is moved and the selected messages are kept on the server.

Your local mail is stored in a folder `/home/<yourlogin>/.thunderbird/<random numbers>.default-default/Mail/Local Folders`. It suffices to backup that folder to have a backup copy of that mail.

Thunderbird also has a function where you can easily archive mails by hitting the letter a after selecting them. So you could archive mails at first on your server this way, then from time to time move mails locally. You could even set it up that mails are moved immediately to a local folder but I would not do that myself: that function is triggered too easily.

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate the help.

Comment: If you appreciate the answer, then please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark. That also shows other users that a usefull answer can be found